# What is recommended way to use fixed size thread pool in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm trying to write benchmark application where certain operation is executed in specified number of threads.

So obvious way to approach it would be to have a thread pool that processes collection of tasks.

How is this done in .NET?

What is recommended way to create fixed size thread pool and run tasks on it?

In Java one would use ExecutorService, is there equivalent class in .NET?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use the ParallelExtensions library and use the `QueuedTaskScheduler` which allows you to configure a fixed number of threads. Then, you can queue tasks to it or use `Parallel` with that scheduler.